# How can I get a list of payment authorizations to me?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Is it possible to just list the currently open authorizations or all authorizations?

The REST API documentation does not give any information about how to obtain the authorization IDs for existing authorizations (here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#authorization).

We have a shopping cart that uses PayPal authorizations (as opposed to charging the card immediately on checkout). The only way for me to authorize payments is to log in on paypal.com, find the authorizations, and capture the funds.

In the API I can't find any information on how to do this automatically.

- I can "list" payments, but only after they have been created trough the API.
- I can "get" a single authorization, but only if I already have the authorization ID.